# control height and width client side with javascript

Tags: javascript, controls

this is my form

```
<form action="#" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" name="..." id="formPhoto" class="fmp">
        <input type="file" name="pho" id="photo" class="inph" accept="image/*">
        <button type="submit" id="subFormPhoto" class="spp">press here</button>
</form>
```

and this is my code JS

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var inputPhoto= document.getElementById('photo');
    inputPhoto.onchange=function(){var photo= this.value; photo.onload=function(){alert(this.width+' '+this.height);};};
</script>
```

my problem is that not visualize `alert(this.width+' '+this.height);`.
as if not load `photo`

Comment: where is the element with id 'insPhotoAlert'. Can you be a little more clear with your question.

Comment: sorry,i adjusted that.

Comment: I want to view  width and height of inputPhoto

Answer (score 0):

`this.value` gives the file name as a string, so your `photo.onload` function isn't really looking at the photo but just some string. If you `alert` or `console.log` `photo` you will see what I mean.

You may wish to consider the [File API](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/), it will work with modern browsers as from HTML 5.

Here's a working example of your code:

```
var inputPhoto = document.getElementById('photo');

inputPhoto.onchange = function() {
  var file = this.files[0];
  var reader = new FileReader();
  var photo  = new Image();

  reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  reader.onload = function(_file) {
    photo.src = _file.target.result;
    photo.onload = function() {
      alert(this.width + ' ' + this.height);
    };
  };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to create what I understood from your question
http://jsfiddle.net/qo8ovmhn/

```
 <input type="file" name="pho" id="photo" class="inph" onchange="myFunction()">
<img id="view" src=""></img>    
<p id="demo"></p>


 <script>
 function myFunction() {
var x = document.getElementById("photo");
var file = x.files[0];
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.readAsDataURL(file);
reader.onload = function(_file) {
 var img = document.getElementById("view");
 img.setAttribute("src",_file.target.result);
 var height = img.offsetHeight;
 var width = img.offsetWidth;
 alert(width + " X " + height);

 };
  }
</script>
```

see if this is what you were looking for.
The change event of the input is called on choosing an image. The image bytes are read and put in an image tag. Then the dimensions of the image are fetched from the height and width of the image component.
You can hide the image by adding a css style of visibility:hidden or opacity:0
Do not give display:none as this will result in height and width of 0px

Finally the dimensions are shown in an alert.